# webview not load local site page using localhost name and port

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to load local hosted site in my webview.

Now if I am try to load like http://dev1:8080/ then it does not work.

but if write IP instead of localhost name like http://192.168.1.120:8080/ then its work fine but using that I am getting cookies null.

I was tried this in computer browser its work fine but I am only able to get cookies when load with http://dev1:8080/

Comment: Try if that works in mobile browser also. If its accessible, then webview will also be able to or else not.

Comment: how does `http://dev1:8080/ ` resolve?

Comment: i was already checked same issue.@Stallion

Comment: @VladMatvienko no. but make some server side changes so now able to access via ip

Comment: `no` can't answer the question `how`.

Comment: @VladMatvienko dont know about network side.

Comment: @VladMatvienko have any solution?

Comment: have you set `dev1` in hosts file to point somewhere?

Comment: @VladMatvienko may be network engineer did. not me

Comment: then you should ask a question `why dev1 is not resolving on the mobile phone?` to your network engineer

Comment: @VladMatvienko i was asked but he is not answering clear.:(

Comment: that is really the problem he should handle. Meanwhile, Are you sure that the PC which can access `dev1` and your phone are on the same network?